# Connect Dronekit and Mission Planner simultaneously to Pixhawk over 3DR radio

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit

I like Dronekit for controlling my copter, and I like Mission Planner for monitoring my copter during a flight.  I'd really like to have both sets of functionality.

Is there a way to connect Dronekit and Mission Planner to the Pixhawk at the same time?  I'm using the 3DR radio set to connect from a laptop on the ground.  If that's not possible, is there a way to relay the connection through Dronekit to Mission Planner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mavproxy to make the initial connection, and then fork it to DK and MP.

`mavproxy.py --master=/dev/ttyUSB0 --out=127.0.0.1:14550 --out=127.0.0.1:14551`

Connect mission planner to UDP port 14550. Connect DK to port 14551.